# How to create input element with div class dynamically in html table?

Tags: javascript, html

I can able to create input element dynamically in html table, But i need to create dynamic `input` element surrounded by `div` using `javascript`

like this,

```
<td>
    <div class="autocomplete">
    <input style="height: 30px !important; width:400px;" class="form-control 
     rightalign" id="productname0">
     </div>
</td>
```

Comment: input tag must be closed: *<input ... />*

Comment: @MarioSantini - No, that's never been true (since even before HTML5) except in XHTML.

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is good to know, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is basic DOM operations:

```js
let td = document.querySelector('td');
let div = document.createElement('div');
let input = document.createElement('input');

div.classList.add('autocomplete');
input.classList.add('form-control');
input.classList.add('rightalign');
input.id = 'productname0';
input.style = 'height: 30px !important; width:400px;';

div.appendChild(input),
td.appendChild(div);
```

```html
<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!. Thanks for answering this basic question.

Comment: No problem, you might want to consider picking your answer (and upvoting, if it helped).

Comment: i would give once i received my criteria to vote (15 rep)

Comment: Picking your answer should not require anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. try something similar this:

```
var i = document.createElement("INPUT");
i.type="text";
i.setAttribute("style","height: 30px !important; width:400px;");
i.className="form-control rightalign";
i.id="productname0";  

Array.prototype.slice.apply( document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete")).map(function(div, j){
    div.appendChild(i.cloneNode(true));
});
```